Error 404 (Not found) when connecting the frontend and backend parts in React. What to do?
I made a feedback form, the client server is working well separately. But when they were combined on the same host when you click send (request feedback by mail ) an error is coming out. Swears at the line in Hero.jsx const response = await fetch("/api/feedback", {
backend  server.js
const express = require('express'); 
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer'); 

const server = express();


server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
server.use(express.json());


server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("public/index.html", { root: __dirname})
})


server.post("/api/feedback", async(req, res) => {
    try {

     const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.mail.ru",
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: "ya@mail.ru",
            pass: "**********"  
        }
     });   

     const { name, phone, message} = req.body;

     await transporter.sendMail({
        from: "ya@mail.ru",
        to: "ya@mail.ru",
        subject: "Тема письма",
        text: `${name} ${phone} ${message}`,
        html: 
        `
        <p>${name}</p>
        <p>${phone}</p>
        <p>${message}</p>
        `


     });

     return res.status(200).send({
        status: 200,
        message: 'Успешня отправка'
     })

    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(500).send({
            status:500,
            message: 'Ошибка при запросе'
        });
    } 
})


server.listen(5000, () => {

    console.log('listening on port 5000'); 

})

script.js
const FEEDBACK_FORM = document.querySelector('#feedback-form');

function sendFeedback(feedback) {
    fetch("/api/feedback" , {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(feedback),
    }).then((response)=>response.json()).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        alert('Успешно');
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        alert('Ошибка');
    });
}

FEEDBACK_FORM.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const feedbackFormData = new FormData(e.target);
    console.log('feedbackFormData', feedbackFormData);
    const feedback = Object.fromEntries(feedbackFormData);
    console.log('feedback', feedback);

    sendFeedback(feedback);
})

Front Hero.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./Hero.module.css";
import { getImageUrl } from "../../utils";

export const Hero = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    message: ""
  });

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const handleCall = () => {
    window.location.href = "tel:**************";
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/feedback", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      
      if (response.ok) {
        alert('Успешно');
        setFormData({
          name: "",
          phone: "",
          message: ""
        });
      } else {
        alert('Ошибка');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert('Ошибка');
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <section className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>*********</h1>
        <p className={styles.description}>
          «Ya» 
        </p>
        <a href="tel:+**********" className={styles.contactBtn} onClick={handleCall}>
          Позвонить
        </a>
        <button onClick={openModal} className={styles.contactBTN}>
          Оставить заявку
        </button>
        {isOpen && (
          <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              value={formData.name}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Имя"
            />
            <input
              type="tel"
              name="phone"
              value={formData.phone}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Телефон"
            />
            <textarea
              name="message"
              value={formData.message}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Сообщение"
            />
            <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
          </form>
        )}
      </div>
      <img
        src={getImageUrl("hero/heroImage.png")}
        alt="Hero image of me"
        className={styles.heroImg}
      />
      <div className={styles.topBlur} />
      <div className={styles.bottomBlur} />
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;

I tried a lot of things To help solve the problem

does the similar request in script.js work

What URL do you have open in your browser when you're viewing the Hero component?

Jaromanda X : yes,   Phil:  http://localhost:5000/

Notably if your services exist on different ports, then /relative/path will not work, since if a page on localhost:5000/something wants to fetch from localhost:3333/relative/path, then /relative/path will falsely point to localhost:5000/relative/path. This is less a code issue (relative paths aside) as much as a configuration/networking setup one, depending on your viewpoint for who is responsible for what.

The url used in fetch() needs to be complete url like http://localhost:5000/api/feedback.
